# Torquebox , Torquespec testing queues can't be fetched in remote_describe block

Tags: torquebox

I'm building a *trigger capturing system* with **Torquebox** and use **Torquespec** for **TDD/BDD** system manages a queue of *captured triggethers* and processes them. Following are the snippets of **torquebox.rb** *config* file and **start_spec.rb** *spec* file

---

#### torquebox.rb

```rb
TorqueBox.configure do

 pool :web, :type => :shared

 service TriggerTrapperService do
   config do
    name 'RTBS triggers trapper service'
   end
 end

 queue '/queues/rtbs_triggers_queue'

end
```

---

#### start_spec.rb

```rb
require 'torquespec'
require 'torquebox-core'
require 'spec_helper'


describe "local test" do
 deploy <<-END.gsub(/^ {4}/,'')
    application:
        root: #{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../app
 END

 remote_describe "remote test" do
  include TorqueBox::Injectors

   it "should work" do
     some_service = fetch('/queues/rtbs_triggers_queue')
     some_service.should.equal? nil
   end
 end
end
```

---

the issue I having is when I fetch the queue **rtbs_triggers_queue** in the remote block it returns **nil** as if the in the testing environment **torquebox.rb** is not being read and I had the same results with the **torquebox.yml** as well, what could be the reason ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that rather than using `fetch` get the specified queue object we need to use

```
TorqueBox::Messaging::Queue.new('/queues/my_queue')
```

Even thought this seems we are creating a new queue what it actually does is get a reference to the queue declared in the `torquebox.rb`